# I watched many youtube videos of so called Christian Prince

Tags: hadith, christianity, bible, scientific-proof

The Christian Prince often debates by citing passages from the Quran and authentic Hadiths. Regrettably, I haven't been able to find videos where Muslim scholars respond to him using a similar approach. Does anyone have recommendations for such videos?

Answer (score 1):

These anti Islamic sites are nothing but outright slander against prophet(s.a). They don't produce any authentic hadith to prove their point. One slander is about Safiyya's marriage to prophet(s.a). They claim that prophet married Safiyya bint Huyayy the same night when her father and brother were killed. Can they produce some authentic proof to support their claim? If not, there is no point in creating videos to refute their baseless claims.

> If only you had said upon hearing it, “How can we speak about such a
> thing! Glory be to You ˹O Lord˺! This is a heinous slander!” [Quran
> 24:16](https://quran.com/24/16)

Answer (score -1):

I personaly observed that he has little classicial arabic knowledge. I commented about a few random segments of random videos . His attitude does not fit to Christian belief as well as any humane manner. He is insulting people, and twisting words and giving different meaning than the well established meanings. This is the reason that He is ignored by Muslim Scholars in general. I will give a few example

1- CP claim that following verses are contradictory.

Quran 2:136(also 285): O believers! say ".. we make no distinction between any of prophets.. "

Quran 2:253 Of those messengers, some of whom We have caused to excel others... ;

My response : In verses 2:285 (also 136) the subject is believers and there is a command. Allah commands believers not to make any difference between prophets. This is forbidden for Muslims. Thus, these verses shows the view from believer point. However, in 2:253 the subject is Allah and the verse shows view from Allah perspective. That is, prophets are also applied to general rule that people are in various degree in both this world and hereafter.. One person may excel other as a general rule. Here is the more proof

Quran 17:21 See how We have made some of them(people) to excel others, and certainly the hereafter is much superior in respect of excellence

2-CP claim that Quran include some foreign words. However, the verse 16:103 says that Quran is pure arabic. This is contradiction.

My response : This is simply an example of a mistranslation. Here is the verse

Quran 16:103. And indeed We know that they (polytheists and pagans) say: "It is only a human being who teaches him (Muhammad)." The tongue of the man they refer to is foreign, while this (the Qur'ân) is a speech Arabeeyun mubeen

The words 'arabeeyun mubeen' is incorrectly and not necessarily translated as 'pure arabic' when in reality it refers to "clear", "manifest", "obvious", etc. as well as its function ("making clear" or "manifesting", i.e., the truth), either of which meanings is dictated by its context. Hence the phrase should be rendered as:

while this (the Qur'ân) is clear Arabic speech.

Thus, this verse has nothing to do with etymology and the presence of foreign words in the Qur'an. It simply points out that the Qur'an cannot be attributed to a foreigner when it has been revealed in clear and eloquent arabic.

Same word mubeen is used in the following verse where it has nothing to do with pure.

Quran 31:11 Such is the Creation of Allah. now show Me what is there that others besides Him have created: nay, but the Transgressors are in manifest(mubeen) error.

The phrase that has been rendered here as 'manifest error' is dalaalim mubeen. Hence, it it obvious that mubeen refers to something clear, especially in the sense that it is obvious.

3- CP claim that Jesus is alive according to Islam

My response :

You decide whether Jesus is died or not according to Quran.

Quran 3:55 God said, "Jesus, I will cause you to die (teveffa) and raise you up to me, and purify you from those who denied the truth, and I will exalt your followers over those who deny you until the Resurrection Day. Then you all will return to me, and I will judge between you in matters about which you disagree.

Quran 5:117 I told them only what You commanded me to say, "Worship God, who is my Lord as well as your Lord." I was a witness to them during my time with them. But after you made me die (teveffa), You were the One watching over them. You witness everything.

In these verses, It is clearly emphasized that Jesus died (teveffa). The word Teveffa (توفىَ) means "taking a soul". This word is used 25 times in the Qur'an. You can check for example verses 4:17, 6:61, 47:27 and others that this word is commonly meant dying.

4- CP claim that how Allah has a son if he has no girl friend..He state that Allah has no son due to the reason that He has no female mate.

My response :Here is the word by word translation where there is no

Quran(6:101) The Ever-Innovating of the heavens and the earth-however does He have a child, and He has no companion, and He created everything, and He is Ever-Knowing of everything?

5- Christian Prens state that the well established word nikahe in arabic has only one meaning that is having sex..

My response: A word can be different meaning according to context. Quran uses the word nikah generally to mean marry..Here is the proof

Quran 33:49 "O believers! If you marry(nikahe) believing women and then divorce them before you touch(sexual intecourse with ) them, they will have no waiting period for you to count, so give them a ˹suitable˺ compensation, and let them go graciously..."

6- CP claim that Jesus is described as Holy One in Quran according to Maryam 19

My response : Here is the Maryam 19 “He responded, “I am only a messenger from your Lord, ˹sent˺ to bless you with a pure(zakiya) son.”....

Dont believe anyone(muslim or non muslim) without searching by yourself.. Muslims usually make mistakes in translations and CP like people uses such deficiencies in İslam. The term zakiya means pure, not holy.. In arabic holy means Quddus.. For example Holy Spirit means Ruhul Quddus.. Furthermore, prophets and angels can be called holy because they represent God.. It does not mean that they are God

Conclusion :
CP generally highlights the misinterpretations of religious scholars throughout history and attributes them to the definition of Islam. This is similar to the type of person who constantly looks for people's flaws. Religion cannot be learned or taught through people's mistakes.